# cannot test my database connection in eclipse

Tags: java, database, eclipse, jdbc

Hye 
 i dont seem to be able to connect the database for my project and i cant figure out why . i already create the database in the Mysql workbench and i still cannot run the jdbc.java

```
package database;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketImpl;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import common_interface.Honeyword;

public class JDBC {

    public static void ConnectDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle://localhost:3306/Honeyword","root","qwertyuiop4595");
            System.out.println("Connected to Database..");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    static Connection con;
```

Comment: Please provide more information like what is the exception you are getting??

Comment: If you want to connect to a MySQL database you need to use the MySQL JDBC driver, not the Oracle JDBC driver.

Comment: Unrelated, but given your imports, your class should probably be splitted into several different classes: awt, swing, net, sql, and concurrent in the same class: yikes.  Using a single static connection, not respecting the Java naming conventions, catching Exception, and ignoring exceptions are also big code smells.

Answer (score 0):

It seem's that you work with MySQL database, and I would suggest you to use the straignt MySQL driver instead of Oracle's:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Honeyword","root","qwertyuiop4595");
```

Post an exception text please.